# Is it possible to disable custom/embedded screenshots in Cypress?

Tags: config, cypress, screenshot

There is an option to disable screenshots in cypress.json but only for "screenshotOnRunFailure", when Cypress automatically takes a screenshot when there is a failure. Is it possible to disable custom screenshot "cy.screenshot()" passing parameter in run command like for video --config video=false. For example:

```
  it('test screenshots', () => {

    cy.get('someElement').click(); // user is redirected to another page
    cy.screenshot();
  
    cy.get('someElement').click();
    cy.screenshot();

  });
```

So, I need to run a command to include and ignore screenshots.

Comment: There's the screenshot API, but I don't see such an option in the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/screenshot-api), so probably it's not possible.

Comment: @savelija did you find a solution to able problem ?